What (new) legal principles can guide the necessary changes in social-economic (tax, social, labour) law due to AI transformation of economy and work?
What (new) legal principles can guide the necessary changes in social-economic (tax, social, labour) law due to AI transformation of economy and work?
I would prefer research trends, authors and papers instead of just listing such principles.

The should be migrated to Politics.SE; Law.SE is about what the law is, not about what it should be or might be.

We can see, that US Supreme Court and European Court of Human Rights consider some principles above the politics and makes their decisions - very basic principles about human rights, about justice, about social rights etc. I have such principles in my mind - whether they stay or changes? That is why my question belongs to legal reasoning realm. I could put it in the text of question, but that is not allowed here.

Your question presumes "necessary changes" but you haven't made it clear what changes you feel are necessary.

@MichaelHall OMG - I created previously the question where I mentioned the issues that may be in need to be addressed and I provided the example how it is being done in other fields (e.g. climate change), but that question is now being closed and heavily downvoted because moderators insisted that no additional information and no clarifications are allowed in the question. And now you are asking me to do the same.

Moderators of SE.Law expect the there are knowlegeable people and any elaboration is expressively prohibited in the questions.

I suspect you do not fit well with a short question, just as you did not fit well with a longer one, because this is more politics than law. Basically you are asking what scholars think the law should be, while Law SE is mostly about what the laws and legal traditions currently are. But then on Politics you might get close votes for "promoting a cause" ... perhaps a sign that your question is no good fit on SE at all. SE is not a discussion site, and shoehorning discussions into questions makes for bad questions.

Yes, politics, or philosophy...  I sorta get what you are getting after, but really what you seek isn't a good fit for a Q&A site like this.  A better fit for a brainstorming session or philosophical "what if" discussion about future trends.

I don't want to discuss these things here, I am just seeking the legal venues and, journals (like Stanford Law Review of European Constitutional Law review) and specific articles that are doing this discussion.

We don't deal with what the law should be at all. That's politics. We only deal in what the law is and so far, AI has only managed to get a very small number of laws set.

A google scholar search brought up this collection of papers -
A History of AI and Law in 50 papers: 25 Years of the International Conference on AI and Law
A link to the document that is not paywalled -
https://intranet.csc.liv.ac.uk/~tbc/publications/ICAIL25AuthorsVersion.pdf

Unfortunately this it not about my topic. I am pretty aware of the Springer journal "AI and law" and its sponsoring association. They are working on automation of law and legal reasoning, they are almost never considering the content or application of law and the report, you provided, is just another proof of it. But there are good new thought - the new journal https://www.lexxion.eu/en/journals/aire/ has just appeared and it touches many areas of the society being transformate by AI, most relevant to my question is the article about Nigeria Film industry and ...

...compensatino rules there due to AI disruptions.

You can make that an answer to your own question.
